# How to get mac address and ip adress using node.js or Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ip, mac-address

We can get the ip and mac address of our computer using node.js.

Is it possible to get the address of Clients computer

Companies like google and Paytm uses mac address to ensure security, how they get that?

Comment: MAC address? I'm not sure that someone can access that

Comment: This is wrongly marked duplicate. The post with which this is marked duplicated discusses about getting the mac address from HTTP request while this post mentions `angular` which runs on client browser 
 and may have a different approach of getting the address. If that is possible or not is a different thing.